# Proving that "at" is a preposition in "he laughed at me"

Tags: prepositions

> He arrived at 10 p.m.

*At* in this sentence is clearly a preposition because it can be replaced with another preposition.

> He laughed at me.

How can we prove that *at* in the above sentence is a preposition?

Comment: _Laugh at_ is a phrasal verb. Some linguists call _at_ a "particle" rather than a "preposition". It doesn't matter what it's called. How it functions and what it means is what's important.

Comment: This rule doesn't always work. You can *"think through a plan" and *"think about a plan"*, but here *"think through"* is a phrasal verb, so *"through"* is a particle and not a preposition. You can tell in this case because you can also *"think a plan through"*. (You can also *"think up a plan"* and *"think over a plan"*; neither of these are prepositions, either.)

Comment: @BillFranke I think in this case the linguists would call the *at* in *laugh at* a *preposition* rather than a *particle* because it must appear before the object: *laugh at him* rather than *\*laugh him at*.

Comment: Different linguists would call it different things for different purposes, often several different things in the same discourse. As Bill and Peter point out, it's the construction that matters; [names are just convenient labels](); terminology is sposta be a help, not a yoke.

Comment: Oh, and you can't ever ***prove*** anything in syntax. Or in any science; only in mathematics, which has no data. The best you can do in science is to argue convincingly for one position or another. By presenting evidence. **Lots** of evidence.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, in "I laughed at him", it functions as a preposition, but it's different in "I don't like to be laughed at", where "laughed at" is a phrasal verb because it's incomplete without the "at". Terminology explains nothing, but it does label things, which may help explain something.

Comment: @BillFranke If you look at someone, and they complain that they don’t like to be looked at, you cannot pretend that those are suddenly two completely different sorts of *at*, one a preposition and the other some theoretical particle. The round hole of Latin’s grammar need not to be contorted to accommodate the square peg of English grammar: just don’t try to stick it there, and you will be just fine.

Comment: @tchrist: Maybe the label and/or function 'preposition' isn't so good for Latin either. That closed set of words usually called prepositions in Latin, though not in the same way as in English, can also be used functionally in other that prepositional phrases (eg prefixes for new word formation).

Comment: Think of them as directional markers that can be either intransitive or transitive. The transitive ones have objects, the intranstive ones don't. Just like verbs. Except that some are multidextrous, like _up_, which not only swings both ways, but forms several types of phrasal verbs as well. That's the tack Geoff Pullum takes in the big grammar.

Answer (score 6):

*Laugh at*, as Bill Franke tells us, is a “phrasal verb” — that is, a construction of the form **V + P** (Verb + Preposition) which must be treated as a single term with a meaning distinct from the use of the two components in merely accidental juxtaposition.

For example:

> In *I laughed at sunrise*, *laugh* is the ordinary intransitive verb meaning “to express mirth”, and *at sunrise* is an ordinary prepositional phrase telling when *I laughed*.
>   In *I laughed at the sunrise*, *laugh at* is a **transitive phrasal verb** meaning “to mock”, and *the sunrise* is its object.

There are two sorts of phrasal verb. In the first sort, the P-component must appear before the object of the verb, so it *looks* exactly a preposition heading a prepositional phrase.  *Laugh at* is phrasal verb of this type; we say

> *John laughed **at** Bill’s stupid mistake.* ... but we do **not** say
>   **John laughed Bill’s stupid mistake **at**.*

Linguists *tend* (but usage varies) to call the P-component here a *preposition*.

In the second sort of phrasal verb the P-component may appear (but is not required to) *after* the object. For example, we may say **either**

> *John ran **over** the pedestrian.* ... **OR**
>   *John ran the pedestrian **over**.*

In this case, linguists tend to call the P-component a *particle*.

Where the particle is placed in these phrasal verbs tends to depend on the “weight” of the object: the longer the NP which acts as the object of the verb, the more likely it is that the particle will be placed before it:

> *John ran over the pedestrian in his path* is more likely than
>   *<sup>?</sup>John ran the pedestrian in his path over*.

Accordingly, the best “test” for whether the P-component in a phrasal verb is a *particle* or a *preposition* is to offer a Native Informant a sentence with the “lightest” possible object — a simple pronoun — preceding the P-component and ask whether that sentence is idiomatic:

> *<sup>?</sup>I laughed him at*.

However, there’s still one tricky bit here: some phrasal verbs have **two** meanings, distinguished by *particular* or *prepositional* use. For instance, *run over* may mean either “knock down and tread upon in running” or “examine from beginning to end”:

> *John ran over the pedestrian in his path* ... or
>   *John ran over the list of alternatives line by line*.

So when you perform your test you must make sure you provide a context:

> *John failed to see the pedestrian in his path and ran him over.*  ... acceptable
>   **John took up the list of candidates and ran it over line by line.* ... not acceptable

Answer (score 5):

A preposition doesn't have to be replaceable by other prepositions to qualify as a preposition itself. *At* is only a preposition, and in many cases it is the only preposition that can be used in particular constructions to express a specific meaning.

Still, in your sentence, *at* is not the only possibility.

> He laughed with me.
>
> He laughed for me.
>
> He laughed near me.
>
> He laughed by me.

And so on would all work, though they would mean different things.

Comment: QED? That proves that?

Answer (score 5):

*Laugh at* is a **prepositional verb**, and *at* is a preposition. Unlike transitive **phrasal verbs**, prepositional verbs do not allow particle movement (the particle in a prepositional verb being a preposition). The preposition ‘always comes before the noun phrase that is the object (‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’). We can’t say **He laughed me at.*

Comment: +1 If only this answer appeared sooner, much hair-splitting could have been avoided on this page.

Comment: "the **particle** in a **prepositional verb** being a **preposition**" nails it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I can endorse the answers analyzing "laugh at" as a phrasal verb, but they have raised some interesting points.

You have identified one diagnostic for telling whether something is a preposition:

> A preposition may be replaced by another preposition without altering the grammaticality of a sentence.

The reason this test fails to show that *at* is a preposition is that the prepositional phrase (i.e., a preposition followed by a noun phrase which acts as a unit) in the test sentence has a special function, meaning roughly "project something in X's general direction, not very accurately." The prepositional phrase is called a *conative argument* in traditional usage. Some examples of sentences with conative arguments:

> - Thomas shot at Carmen.
> - Thomas threw stones at Carmen.
> - Thomas spat at Carmen.
> - Thomas hurled insults at Carmen.
> - Thomas fired at Carmen.

The test mentioned at the start of this answer fails because conative arguments are only formed with *at*. You are not likely to get a grammatical sentence if you interchange conative *at* with another preposition.

There are various other properties of prepositions that can be used in addition to the replacement test, however. One that will be useful here is the *pied-piping* alternation, roughly as follows:

> In a relative clause or a content question, a prepositional phrase can be fronted *in toto*, with both the preposition and noun phrase moving to the front of the clause (*pied-piping*), or only the noun phrase can be fronted, with the preposition itself remaining in its original position (*stranding*).

Here are some examples of this kind of alternation (prepositions in square brackets, object noun phrases in round brackes).

> Thomas laughed [at] (the man). (original sentence)
>   The man [at] (whom) Thomas laughed... (pied-piping)
>   The man (who) Thomas laughed [at]... (stranding)
>   [At] (whom) did Thomas laugh? (pied-piping)
>   (Who) did Thomas laugh [at]? (stranding)

This type of alternation, involving prepositional phrases, does not affect the meaning of the sentences. Similar alternations are not available for other word classes, so *at* is a preposition.

Comment: You don't have to endorse answers that analyze "laugh at" as a phrasal verb. If you don't like that classification, you can take it up with Collins COBUILD. Argue with the lexicographers who wrote their dictionary of phrasal verbs. Don't insist that you're any more of an expert on this topic than they are. You're still an amateur & will be for a few more years. What's the point? Do you think that a label explains anything? If so, you haven't been paying attention to the real world.

Comment: I'd like to offer my hearty applause to @BillFranke for his spirited and thoughtful defense of the phrasal verb analysis. as ever, the community can only rejoice when a diversity of viewpoints on important issues in English grammar abound.

Comment: The trouble with constituency tests: (1) **A word of caution is warranted when employing these tests, since they often deliver contradictory results.** (Wikipedia). (2) Reasonably accomplished linguists often cite a particular test which supports their pet analysis. Here, the degrees of 'binding' between the verb-and-prepositiony-thingy and between the -thingy-and-completer are important. In _he arrived at 10pm_, _at 10pm_ is surely the more strongly-bound. In _he took off Tommy Cooper_, _took_ and _off_ are more strongly-bound. In _he laughed at me / adversity_, we have intermediate cases.

Comment: *Conative* is a new term to me, so I may be misunderstanding it; but it appears to me that it is used not of directed action *tout simple* but of attempted directed action *distinguished from accomplished directed action*, eg *He kicked at the ball* distinguished from *He kicked the ball*. This is not the case with *laughed at*. ... But your answer raises fascinating issues which I don't think can be addressed in Comments, and which are not really relevant to OP's question; I intend to raise a separate Question when I can get my thoughts together.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth +1 for what turns out to be skepticism about labels and functions. Whatever it is, it's still 'at'.

Comment: @StoneyB great comments and I'm looking forward to seeing your question.

Comment: @j: Thank you for your graciousness. I'm merely a reporter, not an advocate. I have no stake in whether the phrasal verb analysis is correct. It may be helpful; it may not. It's not an article of faith for me. Even the great Aristotle, a founder of modern physics, once believed that stones fell to Earth because it was "in their nature" to do so. I don't mean to compare myself with Aristotle: He was a genius but I'm not. English usage discussion are rife with controversy because of conflicting opinions & contradictory evidence. That makes some of them interesting, others not.

Comment: Thomas threw stones to Carmen.

Answer (score 1):

Prove it by consulting a [dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/at):

> **at<sup>1</sup>** *preposition*:
>   5. expressing the object of a look, thought, action, or plan

Comment: Yes, a dictionary can provide what I would call _evidence_ rather than _proof_ that _at_ is a preposition. Were it only a preposition, however, the string *"I don't like to be looked" would be meaningful rather than incomplete. To be complete, the string must be "I don't like to be **looked at**", which means that it's part of the verb and, contrary to its name, not a **pre**-position but a **post**-position or, as some linguists maintain, a "particle" attached to a phrasal verb rather than a  preposition that expresses the object of a look. Again, terminology fails to explain anything.

Comment: @Bill: You can say "windows are for looking out of, and not climbing out of". Does that mean that in "climb out of" and  "look out of" are phrasal verb?

Comment: @P: That's a good question. But it's one that has great value only to a few categories of people: professional linguists, lexicographers, taxonomists, & dogmatists. Does knowing whether they are phrasal verbs it help anyone understand how to use the language? If yes, it's worth knowing the answer to. If no, then it isn't. But, as I've said in another comment on this page, you can take issue with the lexicographers at Collins COBUILD: They & not I put it in their dictionary of phrasal verbs. Does it matter whether guns kill, bullets kill, or people who use guns & bullets kill? Not to the dead.

Comment: One authority does not make a tablet-of-stone ruling (except in the original case).

Answer (score 1):

After reading a lot of the above answers and comments, I feel that people are coming at this problem from different and entrenched viewpoints.

First, let me say that I feel it is counter-productive to view multi-word verbs (eg take in = deceive, turn down = reject, show up = embarrass or appear on the scene) as anything other than the equivalents of single-word verbs – even if they are separable (eg She looked up a friend. / She looked a friend up.)

Second, however, though there are obvious MWVs (eg the plane took off) and obvious V + PP constructions (eg he ran to the man), there are many isomorphic constructions in English that are difficult to determine as being in one camp or the other. To quote Phil Hunt (who uses the term 'phrasal verb' in the way ESL teachers do but which term I avoid) (and also plumps for 'preposition' in his example) in [this article at Wordwizard](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=22087&hilit=phrasal+verbs+struggling&start=15):

> This [distinction] becomes even further blurred when using verb
>   combinations such as 'look for'. Is it a phrasal verb or a
>   verb+preposition[?] The basic element of the verb, that of sight, has
>   not changed, but the meaning of 'search' has been added by the
>   addition of the preposition [-or-is-it]. One of the problems that I
>   see many teachers struggling with is how to classify these 'phrasal'
>   verbs which seem to have a foot in both camps. Perhaps this is one
>   reason H&P have decided to update the definitions. ...

I'd say that *laugh at someone* is another hard-to-classify case – the basic meaning of the verb *laugh* is retained, but an element of *ridicule / put down* is (or may be) added. Which would make it not the same usage as in *laughed for sheer joy at the glorious sight of the canyon walls lit by the setting sun*.