# Difference between verb+preposition and phrasal verbs

Tags: grammar

I am reading a book on grammar. Now I can't understand the difference between the `verb+preposition` and `phrasal verbs`. For example

> He never thinks about(or of) other people.

and

> put on your coat

Why this book call `think about` a `verb+preposition` and `put on` a `phrasal verb`. What's the difference between them?

Here are another examples about this subject

#### *verb+preposition*

- ask (somebody) for
  A man stopped me and asked me for money.
- belong to ...
  Does this book belong to you?
- talk to somebody about something
  Did you talk to Paul about the problem?

#### *phrasal verbs*

- Turn over
  Turn over and look at the next page
- turn on
  It was dark, so I turned on the light.
- bring back
  You can take my umbrella but please bring it back.

I don't know the difference clearly.

Comment: I don't know if this is the formal difference, but in the examples you categorize as phrasal verbs, there is a (sometimes only slight) difference in meaning when compared to the verb on its own. E.g. *turn on* does not involve exactly the same action as *turn*. Compare this with e.g. *talk to*, which is the same action as *talk* but with an explicit indirect object.

Comment: This question has been addressed at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96822/proving-that-at-is-a-preposition-in-he-laughed-at-me/96856#96856 ; a full answer is probably a few decades away.

Comment: Two problems here are that **a)** the term *phrasal verb* is used by differently by different authorities and **b)** a simple division into two categories does not adequately describe this complex topic (see the first two paragraphs of John Lawler's answer).

Comment: Yeah, and I didn't even get to sentence (4), which is different yet.

Comment: @DavidR: _Talk to_ has both a transparent (chat with) and a semi-transparent (reprove) (cf give someone a good talking to) sense. It's the semi- (/quarter- / tenth- / nine-tenths-) transparent ones that make classification so difficult. '_Run_ up a hill' and '_run up_ a bill' are the easy ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several types of `phrasal verb`, and several types of `verb + preposition`. Not all of them are constituents, they serve different functions, they're all irregular as hell, and they're all governed by the matrix verb.

**Every** verb has its own assortment of special idioms, affordances, prohibitions, requirements, and irregularities. There is such immense variation in these details that such matters are considered part of the meaning of the verb; certainly they are strongly affected by the meanings. Square and cube that variation for phrasal verbs, since there are far more phrasal verbs in English than there are single-word verbs.

Some varieties can be examined in this freshman grammar [homework problem](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/EnglishPhrasalVerbs.pdf). Examples of different types, from there:

Sentences (1) and (2) show two normal verb + prep constructions, from the same verb: *look at*, with transitivizing *at*; and *look for*, a transitive idiom meaning 'search'. Both of them require that the preposition precede the object (which may be thought of either as the object of the preposition, or as the direct object of the transitive verb + prep construction), even if that object is a pronoun. It makes no difference to most prepositions whether their object is a noun or a pronoun  (ungrammatical sentences are marked with an asterisk *******):

- *I looked for Einstein* ~ **I looked Einstein for* ~ *I looked for him* ~ **I looked him for*.

Sentence (3), on the other hand, is a real transitive phrasal verb. There are two characteristics of phrasal verbs that help to distinguish them. Both tests have limitations, however. The most important one, and the easiest test to administer, is the difference between the pattern of asterisks in the second and third columns, where pronoun objects force the difference.

There is a syntactic rule (called Particle Shift in the literature) that applies to **transitive** phrasal verbs only, and imposes a special requirement on pronoun objects. Thus, with a real phrasal verb like *look up* 'research (v)', the particle may appear either before or after a Noun object, but must appear after a Pronoun object.

- *I looked up Einstein ~ I looked Einstein up* ~ **I looked up him* ~ *I looked him up*.

Note, however, that this test is helpful only with transitive phrasal verbs. There are plenty of intransitive phrasal verbs, too, but there's no object to test with. Many transitive phrasal verbs can appear also intransitively, e.g *take off, move away*, often with a different sense (*He took it off ~ The plane took off*), or not (*He moved it away ~ It moved away*).

The second useful characteristic is that a phrasal verb is stressed on the **particle**, at least as much as on the verb, and maybe more. A V + PP construction like *look at*, on the other hand, is stressed on the *verb*, not the preposition.

- *He looked **up** the word. ~ He **looked** at the word.*

That's because prepositions are rarely stressed, except for emphasis (***In*** the toilet, you idiot!);
they're sposta slide by like articles and conjunctions to grease the way into the object, which is the informational part. They're not sposta distract, so they're unstressed, and therefore reduced, so we get common contractions like *sposta* and *lookit*.

Unfortunately, stress is not represented in English writing, so that distinction is not helpful for readers.

Comment: John, thanks for your helpful information. Now, I can understands the rules you said, but, for instance, `over` in the phrasal verbs like `get over` and `think over`, is still unclear for me to decide it a particle or a preposition. Is there a method to make this decision? Does it only rely on the memory?

Comment: The real difference between the types is whether the constituents of the Verb phrase are divided this way ***[[V + P] N]*** (phrasal verb) or this way ***[V [P + N]]*** (verb + prep phrase). The tests I mentioned distinguish constituents, which is why they're useful. Constituency is the most important concept in syntax -- syntactic constructions and rules apply **only** to constituents, **never** to strings that are not constituents.

Comment: I fully agree with your first comment here. However, to quote Wikipedia: [Constituency] tests are rough-and-ready tools that grammarians employ to reveal clues about syntactic structure. But  ... these tests ...often deliver contradictory results. Some syntacticians even arrange the tests on a scale of reliability, with less-reliable tests treated as useful to confirm constituency though not sufficient on their own. Failing to pass a single test does not mean that the unit is not a constituent, and conversely, passing a single test does not mean necessarily that the unit is a constituent.

Comment: Yes. Constituency can change. That's where phrasal verbs come from in the first place, and there are more developing all the time, at different degrees of constituency. It's quite common to find that two different constituent structures nevertheless point to the same thing in certain cases, and that different people have different perceptions of the constituent structures. Haj Ross's paper [_Nouniness_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Nouniness.pdf) talks about the squishy nature of the category label _Noun_.

Comment: Different verbs, different alternations, different prepositions, etc. [Levin 1993](http://linguistlist.org/issues/4/4-1102.html) is a good example of how governed alternations vary, and how the verb classes that govern them cohere semantically.

Comment: There may also be other criteria. You can ask whether the preposition can go before who/which. *"That is the house at which I was looking"* sounds okay (if quite formal), but **"These are the children after whom I was looking"* sounds utterly awful. Does that means "look after" should be counted as a phrasal verb, where as "look at" is just a verb + preposition?

Comment: Pied piping requires a PP constituent; it doesn't apply to V + P constituents. But there are several intermediate stages; if one insists on binary divisions, one is apt to get cut on the edges. Language is alive, and everything alive is messy because it's constantly changing.

Comment: Re the examples in your homework problem link: could you explain what's up with - (a) "He **looked over** the picture", (b) "He **ran over** the dog", and (c) "He **looked out** the window"? What are they: phrasal verbs, verb + prep constructions, or something else? / For (c), my guess is that its deviance has to do with the fact that "looked out the window" is actually the elided form of "looked out *of* the window" -- where *of* can only be elided when followed by "window", and perhaps some other nouns too, but not pronouns. I don't have a guess for the other two sentences, though.

Comment: _Look out the window_ is V + PP, _run over_ and _look over_ are ambiguous. Intonation and rhythm might disambiguate.

Answer (score 2):

I always had students start with the verb "put" and generate as many phrasal verbs from it as they could.  Put on, put in, put over, put out, put up, put up with, put down, etc. etc.  In each case, they could see that each one has a different meaning than the verb *put*.  *Think about* and *think of* have essentially the same meaning, because there's always an object of your thinking, so to say.  You have to think about or think of *something.*  *Think over* is a little bit different -- it will take more time than just thinking.  Same with the example @Peter Shor offers -- *look at* is very different from *look after*.  And the adjective clause criterion is a good one.

Comment: No disrespect to John, but this helps me understand the difference far more neatly and concisely. I like your example with the various "put" phrasal verbs.

Comment: @Leo King An ELL rather than an ELU answer, perhaps?